# Secure Admin must be enabled to access the DAS remotely - access Glassfish config page

Tags: server, 18.10, glassfish

My environment is Ubuntu 18.10. It is a new installation, no firewall or processes that run on Glassfish ports.

I installed Glassfish 5 on the server. Java 8, because Glassfish doesn't support any newer. And when I tried to access my config page, of course it gave me a "Secure Admin must be enabled to access the DAS remotely".

Then I proceed to change my admin password with the following commands:

```
./asadmin start-domain

./asadmin change-admin-password
```

- I entered my password and retype it =>

> "Command change-admin-password executed successfully."

```
./asadmin enable-secure-admin
```

=>

> "You must restart all running servers for the change in secure admin to take effect. Command enable-secure-admin executed successfully."

```
./asadmin stop-domain
./asadmin start-domain
```

That is it and it should work. My server is running, I can access my main Glassfish page, but when I'm trying to access the config page it says it didn't find any page with that port.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm struggling with this simple installation.